# Can't execute global Node.js module from Bash shell script (Truffle)?

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, npm, truffle

I installed Truffle, the Ethereum development toolkit, on my Ubuntu 14.04 PC.  I can execute it easily from a terminal window by simply typing "truffle".  However, when I try to execute Truffle from a Bash shell script, I get the following error:

```
ide-do-truffle.sh: line 3: truffle: command not found
```

The line inside the shell script is just:

```
truffle compile --network local
```

How can I execute Truffle from within a shell script?

If someone can also explain what goes on behind the scenes when you execute a globally installed Node.JS package like Truffle, that would be helpful too.

Comment: Either specify the path to _truffle_, or add the directory, where _truffle_ is located, to your `PATH` variable.

Comment: Try `echo $SHELL` in your terminal window. It is possible your shell is not bash. Also check that your script is indeed running with bash, rather than some other sh-family shell. It could be the case that the path to `truffle` is in your `PATH` for one shell, but not for your bash shell. Also, if the bash script runs as a different user than you, the `PATH` might be different.

Comment: @ShaneBishop

Result of `echo $SHELL` is: /bin/bash

Comment: Try `echo $PATH` in both your terminal window and in your script just before your `truffle` line, and compare the two.

Comment: @ShaneBishop  That was it.  Thanks.  For some reason, the IDE I was using to shell to the shell script was altering the path in an unfriendly way.  If you want to change your comment to an answer I will upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible the `PATH` in your terminal window is not the same as the `PATH` that your shell script sees.

Try `echo "$PATH"` in both your terminal window and in your script just before your `truffle` line in your script, and compare the two. If there is a difference, then the problem is with the `PATH` in your shell script.